# Parse data from sensor without delimeters

Tags: serial, sensors, arduino-due

Im using a variant of Arduino Due embedded on a ARM (Udoo). And I have connected a Medlab SPO2 Pearl 200 sensor to Serial1.

Im just trying to parse input from Serial1 to Serial, in a human-readable format (Hexadecimal).

The protocol is described in this image:
[image: Protocol SPo2]

And using this Arduino code I reveice two times the "no finger detected line"

```
int lineLength = 16;
int spo2read[16];
int readed = 0;
 if (Serial1.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial1.read();
    if (readed < lineLength) {
      spo2read[readed] = inByte;
    }
    readed++;
    if (readed == lineLength) {
      Serial.print("SPO2: ");
      for (int i = 0; i <= lineLength; i++) {
        Serial.print(spo2read[i], HEX);
        Serial.print( delimeter);
      }
      Serial.println("");

      readed = 0;
    }

  }
```

Output with no finger is:

```
SPO2: A,FB,2,F9,0,FA,0,FC,A,FB,2,F9,0,FA,0,FC,0,
```

Buf if I put my finger, all is messed up:

```
SPO2: 7C,74,6B,62,5A,51,4A,42,3B,34,30,2E,2F,30,31,33,0,
SPO2: 36,38,3B,3E,3D,3C,3C,3B,3B,38,34,2F,2C,2B,2B,29,0,
SPO2: 24,21,1E,1D,1E,1E,1F,20,22,24,26,28,2B,2D,30,32,0,
SPO2: 35,37,39,3C,3E,40,42,44,45,4A,4F,53,55,57,59,5C,0,
SPO2: 5E,60,61,F9,0,FA,0,FC,1A,FB,0,F8,62,62,62,63,0,
```

Sensor doesn't sends a \n or \r so I don't know exactly how to parse the data

Comment: It says there is a marker byte. You have to look for the marker byte to know when the message has ended.

Comment: as per http://www.medlab-gmbh.de/english/downloads/pearl100_144.pdf page 13 marker bytes and example C code page 16 are values greater than or equal than F0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the source code available on the Medlab web, and do some "modifications" to be Arduino compatible.
I dont wanna the waveform data, because my final program will do the waveforms acording the data received, so I don't "listen" to the waveform packet

```
boolean startbyte = false; 
byte buf = 0;

  while (Serial1.available() > 3)
  {
    buf = Serial1.read();
    if (buf > 0xfc)
    {
      buf = Serial1.read();
    }


    if ((startbyte == true) && buf > 0xF7)
    {
      startbyte = false;
    }

    if (buf > 0xf7 && startbyte == false)
    {
      //startbyte = true;
      if (buf == 0xf8)
      {
        startbyte = true;
      }

      if (buf > 0xf8)
      {
        byte RX = buf;
        buf = Serial1.read();
        if (buf > 0xfc)
        {
          buf = Serial1.read();
        }

        if (RX == 0xf9)
        {
          //SPO = buf;
          Serial.print("SV:");
          Serial.print(buf, DEC);
          Serial.println();
        }

        else if (RX == 0xfa)
        {
          //Pulse = buf;
          Serial.print("SPV:");
          Serial.print(buf, DEC);
          Serial.println();
        }
        else if (RX == 0xfb)
        {
          //Status = buf;
          Serial.print("StV:");
          Serial.print(buf, DEC);
          Serial.println();
        }

        else if (RX == 0xfc)
        {
          //quality = buf;
          Serial.print("QV:");
          Serial.print(buf, DEC);
          Serial.println();
          Serial.println();
        }
        else { }
      }


    }
    else if (startbyte == true)
    {
     //Waveform data
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I don't think it is all mixed up

as per geometrikal use the markers to parse the data stream

I believe your above sample data started mid-stream during the 0xF8 of the wave form.

```
F8,...
...,7C,74,6B,62,5A,51,4A,42,3B,34,30,2E,2F,30,31,33,0,36,38,3B,3E,3D,3C,3C,3B,3B,38,34,2F,2C,2B,2B,29,0,24,21,1E,1D,1E,1E,1F,20,22,24,26,28,2B,2D,30,32,0,35,37,39,3C,3E,40,42,44,45,4A,4F,53,55,57,59,5C,0,5E,60,61
F9,0
FA,0
FC,1A
FB,0
F8,62,62,62,63,0,...
```

I believe reading this as a finite length does not portray the data for easy interpetation. Given that 0xF8 is a variable length protocol.

Where the reparse of your data initially appears to be legitimate parse.

That said I do read the SPO2, Pulse as zero. Where it may be likely the sensor has not finished its reading and auto gain cycles.